# Kruskal Algorithm convert with vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, kruskals-algorithm

I've a question, I'm working on a implementation of Kruskal Algorithm, i finished it, and it's working, but there's a problem, i've used a "static" array 2D, (input by user, but Limited to 100).
How can i convert it in dynamic allocation or using vector?
I prefer vector, but i don't know how to "modify, and insert" item in a vector of vector.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks,
Bye

There's the code:

```
class kruskal
{
private:
    int n; //no of nodes
    int noe; //no edges in the graph
    int graph_edge[100][4];

    int tree[10][10];

    int sets[100][10];
    int top[100];
public:
    int read_graph();
    void initialize_span_t();
    void sort_edges();
    void algorithm();
    int find_node(int );
    void print_min_span_t();
};

int kruskal::read_graph()
{
cout<<"This program implements the kruskal algorithm\n";
cout<<"Enter the no. of nodes in the undirected weighted graph";
cin>>n;
noe=0;

cout<<"Enter the weights for the following edges ::\n";

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
        {
        cout<<i<<" , "<<j;
        int w;
        cin>>w;
            if(w!=0)
            {
            noe++;
            graph_edge[noe][1]=i;
            graph_edge[noe][2]=j;
            graph_edge[noe][3]=w;
        }
    }
}
// print the graph edges
cout<<"\n\nThe edges in the given graph are::\n";
for(int i=1;i<=noe;i++)
{
    cout<<" < "<<graph_edge[i][1]
    <<" , "<<graph_edge[i][2]
    <<" > "<<graph_edge[i][3]<<endl;

}
}

void kruskal::sort_edges()
{
/**** Sort the edges using bubble sort in increasing order**************/
for(int i=1;i<=noe-1;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=noe-i;j++)
    {
        if(graph_edge[j][3]>graph_edge[j+1][3])
        {
        int t=graph_edge[j][1];
        graph_edge[j][1]=graph_edge[j+1][1];
        graph_edge[j+1][1]=t;

        t=graph_edge[j][2];
        graph_edge[j][2]=graph_edge[j+1][2];
        graph_edge[j+1][2]=t;

        t=graph_edge[j][3];
        graph_edge[j][3]=graph_edge[j+1][3];
        graph_edge[j+1][3]=t;
    }
}
}

// print the graph edges

cout<<"\n\nAfter sorting the edges in the given graph are::\n";
for(int i=1;i<=noe;i++)
cout<<""<< graph_edge[i][1]
<<" , "<<graph_edge[i][2]
<<" > ::"<<graph_edge[i][3]<<endl;
}

void kruskal::algorithm()
{
    // ->make a set for each node
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
    sets[i][1]=i;
    top[i]=1;
    }

cout<<"\nThe algorithm starts ::\n\n";

for(int i=1;i<=noe;i++)
{
int p1=find_node(graph_edge[i][1]);
int p2=find_node(graph_edge[i][2]);

    if(p1!=p2)
    {
        cout<<"The edge included in the tree is ::"
        <<" < "<<graph_edge[i][1]<<" , "
        <<graph_edge[i][2]<<" > "<<endl<<endl;

        tree[graph_edge[i][1]][graph_edge[i][2]]=graph_edge[i][3];
        tree[graph_edge[i][2]][graph_edge[i][1]]=graph_edge[i][3];

        // Mix the two sets

        for(int j=1;j<=top[p2];j++)
        {
            top[p1]++;
            sets[p1][top[p1]]=sets[p2][j];
        }

        top[p2]=0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Inclusion of the edge "
        <<" < "<<graph_edge[i][1]<<" , "
        <<graph_edge[i][2]<<" > "<<"forms a cycle so it is removed\n\n";
    }
}
}

int kruskal::find_node(int n)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=noe;i++)
    {
        for(int j=1;j<=top[i];j++)
        {
        if(n==sets[i][j])
            return i;
        }
    }

return -1;
}

void kruskal::print_min_span_t()
{
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
    cout<<tree[i][j]<<"\t";
cout<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: [OT] : Note that indexing in C/C++ begins at `0`. So you may replace all `for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)` by `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create struct or class edge;

```
struct Edge {
    int v, u, w;

    Edge(int v, int u, int w) : v(v), u(u), w(w) {}

    bool operator < (const Edge& c) const{
         if (w != c.w)
             return w < c.w;
         if (v != c.v)
             return v < c.v;
         return u < c.u;
    }
}
```

Then you can store graph as vector of edges

```
vector<edge> es;
....
cin >> v >> u >> w;
if (w != 0) {
    es.push_back(Edge(v, u, w));
}
```

Also, because operator < is defined in class Edge, you can sort edges using built-in C++ sort algorithm

```
#include <algorithm>
....
std::sort(es.begin(), es.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vvi;

vvi.push_back(std::vector<int>());  // Push back a new vector, as vvi[0]
vvi[0].push_back(123);  // Push back a new integer, as vvi[0][0]

std::cout << "vvi[0][0] = " << vvi[0][0] << '\n';  // Prints 123
```

Comment: Yes, i've tried to do somethink like that, but i got problem with the method insert of a vector... crash program..
something like that: gg.insert(it+j+1, g); ...got in crash the program

Comment: @Raid3nz Well since you don't show the actual code you have problem with (only the code that works) it's hard (if not impossible) to figure out what the problem might be.